# As3 Bitmap font native support?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap-fonts

Recently i have discover many video tutorial regarding bitmap font performance enhance. I would love to use in my existing project, however my project is too late to implement starling framework, just wondering if there is any way which naively support bitmap fonts?

Cheers
Bill

Comment: You can implement it yourself without hassle by creating sprite fonts and then drawing them onto transparent canvases. That however is a project in its own and is something I don't think you're going to get a detailed answer on. I suggest trying to create Bitmap drawn text fields yourself and then coming here when you run into issues.

Comment: @MartyWallace Thanks Marty That's what i am implemented at this stage using bitmapdraw. Hope we have more powerful stuff on the way :)